# Error "indefined reference to" while compiling MYSQL Program

Tags: python, mysql, c, compilation

Im trying to compile my program that uses MYSQL Library.
These are my includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
```

And these are the errors:

```
/tmp/ccs0iJn4.o: In function `toMysql':
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x32d): undefined reference to `mysql_init'
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x373): undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect'
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x38f): undefined reference to `mysql_query'
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x39d): undefined reference to `mysql_close'
/tmp/ccs0iJn4.o: In function `parseGlobalStats':
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x3f1): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x412): undefined reference to `xmlNodeListGetString'
/tmp/ccs0iJn4.o: In function `parseStreamNet':
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x44f): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x493): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x4b4): undefined reference to `xmlNodeListGetString'
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x4cf): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x4f0): undefined reference to `xmlNodeListGetString'
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x50b): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x52c): undefined reference to `xmlNodeListGetString'
/tmp/ccs0iJn4.o: In function `parseDoc':
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x557): undefined reference to `xmlParseFile'
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x598): undefined reference to `xmlDocGetRootElement'
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x5d4): undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc'
ice2mysql2.c:(.text+0x60e): undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Im compiling with this:

```
gcc -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lxml2 -lmysqlclient -o ice2mysql2 ice2mysql2.c
```

If u Want to see the intire program:

[THE PROGRAM](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=A277335163AED593!205&authkey=!AJTYZVs8Gn6rdmo)

I want to know what is happening, please help...Thx!

Comment: For me it looks like compiler/linker can't find compiled libraries (in linux probably files with .so or .a extension) to link it to main program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libraries you link to must be mentioned last:

```
 gcc -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu  -o ice2mysql2 ice2mysql2.c -lxml2 -lmysqlclient
```